# Excel/Visual Basic Macro on Hidden Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Ive written a macro that takes some source data and writes it onto several sheets, which id like to remain hidden before and after the macro has run. Having written the Macro, when I run it it only updates a few records on each sheet (for instance on the first hidden sheet it updates 21 rows out of over 1000. What is the reason for this happening? Surely it should update them all or none of them? Im not getting any errors either. Ive tried

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("FT Raw").Visible = True
Worksheets("L1").Visible = True
Worksheets("L2").Visible = True
Worksheets("L3").Visible = True
Worksheets("L4").Visible = True
```

But still only 21 rows get updated.

Update: This is the code that is running on each sheet

```
endval = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To endval
    If Not Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
        splitted = Split(Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "A"), ",")
        Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "B") = splitted(0)
        Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "C") = splitted(1)
        Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "D") = splitted(2)
        If Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "D") = "1" Then
            Sheets("L1").Cells(j, "A") = Trim(splitted(0))
            Sheets("L1").Cells(j, "B") = Trim(splitted(3))
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: we'd need to see the code that updates the sheets. It's also not normally necessary to make the sheets visible to work on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Edit.  You need to specify the Sheet("FT Raw") in your endval calc.

Try this set `endval = Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(Sheets("FT Raw").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and proceed with the remainder of your code.

(You could also use `endval = Sheets("FT Raw").UsedRange.Rows.Count` *only* if you don't have blank cells at the top of the column)

Lucky last, you don't have to unhide these sheets at all to run the code.  By all means do so to debug but when running in anger it's not necessary.

Comment: When running the sheets unhidden the whole code functions perfectly, counting all the way down to row 1000. It is only when hidden that it stops after 20 lines, thats whats confusing me.

Comment: I suspect that is because you are running it from "FT Raw" when it is unhidden.  How many rows do you have on the *active* worksheet you are running it from when "FT Raw" is hidden?

Comment: This seems to be getting close, if i run it with FT Raw unhidden and the L1/L2/L3/L4 sheets hidden then it works fine. Previously the active sheet was a pivot table. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Change your line `endval = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` to what I have (`endval = Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(Sheets("FT").Rows.Count, 1).Row` and it should work

Comment: That does work, but it seems to take a lot longer than my previous use of endval to run through everything, can you think of a reason for that?

Comment: Yeah, because I screwed up my formula.  It was looping through every single cell even past the used range.  Try the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the hiding of sheets - even if a sheet is hidden, you can still modify it with VBA. (Only if it is protected, you need to unprotect it.)

Lookig at your code, I do not see, where `j` is initialized - and under which circumstances column D in your sheet `FT raw`is equal to `"1"`.

I suggest you initialize j in the top, e.g. if you want to add the rows using

```
 j = Sheets("L1").Range(Rows.Count, 1).End.(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Then, after running the macro (for a check), filter column D in your raw sheet with an Autofilter for the value `1` and see if that matches the number of entries in sheet `L1`.

Comment: I do initialise it earlier in the code, I didnt put it into the original post as I thought it unnecessary to show. Column "D" is equal to 1 in multiple places but doesnt seem to relate to why only 20 of them are being found

Comment: try debugging it then: go through the code with <kbd>F9</kbd> and if a line is skipped, look at the value. Alternatively, add an else statement `Else Debug.Print Sheets("FT Raw").Cells(i, "D")` to see what values are skipped.